# ASP.NET Core IDX10503: Signature validation failed. Token does not have a kid. But it's a symmetric key

Tags: validation, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I generate a JWT in this method when receiving a request.

```
private string CreateToken(User user)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.UserId.ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email)
            };

            var appSettingsToken = _configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value;
            if (appSettingsToken == null) 
            {
                throw new Exception("Le jeton est nul.");
            }

            SymmetricSecurityKey key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(appSettingsToken));
            SigningCredentials credentials = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);

            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                SigningCredentials = credentials
            };

            JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            SecurityToken token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

            return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
        }
```

The token generated seems perfectly valid, verified in jwt.io and even authenticated through middleware. But when trying to return user data here:

```
`[HttpGet("access-token")]
        public IActionResult GetUserFromToken()
        {
            var token = HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString().Replace("Bearer ", "");
            Console.WriteLine("token = " + token);
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value!);
            if (key == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Le jeton est nul.");
            }
            var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false
            };

            SecurityToken validateToken;
            var claimsPrincipal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, tokenValidationParameters, out validateToken);
            var userIdString = claimsPrincipal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value; // error occurs here
            if (!int.TryParse(userIdString, out int userId))
            {
                return BadRequest("Le ID utilisateur est invalide.");
            }

            var userInfo = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == userId);

            if (userInfo == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("no user info found");
            }

            var user = new
            {
                userInfo.UserId,
                userInfo.Email,
            };

            return Ok(user);

        }`
```

I receive the aforementioned error "IDX10503" claiming that token verification has failed, that it's missing a "kid".

I'm really not advanced in knowledge when it comes to JWT and validations, but looking for solutions made me understand that a "kid" should not apply to symmetric keys? As far as I know that's what I'm using, in both functions, but the application is still looking for a "kid"?
I'm using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer v 7.0.10.
At this point I feel it's either a minute detail I overlooked despite having gone through my code many times, or a problem with package versions.
Any pointers or clue are welcome, thanks.